# Change dead disk in DPM 2010

Tags: scdpm

I was backuping data on an 1Gb hard drive with DPM 2010.
This disk died but I replace it with another 1Gb hard drive.

But I don't find how to recreate data structure on this new drive from previous protection group.

Protection group were red. I delete the disk in "administration > disks", now protection group are green but they don't save data and I can't see any menu to change the disk destination.

how to do ?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The previous answer is nice when you have previous disk which is working and want to migrate on another and copy previous replica.

In the case you want to replace a failed hard disk I found a command to do that.

First, add the new disk to storage pool in administration tab and then remove the failed drive.

then start powershell dpm command and type :

```
DPMSYNC -Reallocatereplica
```

This will recreate replica on the new drive of the storage pool.

hope it help some.

Comment: After this command all replicas will be mark as "manual replica creation pending". To correct this just relaunch a consistency check on all replicas.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use the MigrateDatasourceDataFromDPM.ps1 PowerShell command in the DPM shell.  More details on the command are available on Techent - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff399384.aspx

The command would be similar to this:

```
$disk = Get-DPMDisk –DPMServerName DPMTestServer 
./MigrateDatasourceDataFromDPM.ps1 –DPMServerName DPMTestServer –Source $disk[0] –Destination $disk[1]
```

However, I would first run **get-dpmdisk -dpmservername myserver** to determine which disks you are going to use.  For example, first disk listed would be $disk[0] in the above command, and the third disk would be $disk[2].

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will work:

1. Under Management -> Disks tab, add the new disk.
2. Under Protection -> Right click the protection group, Modify Disk Allocation

DPM Disk(s) should be redundant; DPM's D2D backup wasn't designed for very small environments where you have a single non-redundant disk.

Comment: I tried that but I can't do nothing in this window. Even if the new disk is present under "Management -> Disks tab".

here is the screen shot of the  "Modify Disk Allocation" window (the ui is in french) :

http://img189.imageshack.us/img189/8494/capturehnc.png